# how to check reponse equal a object with spring boot mvc?

Tags: java, mockmvc

I want to check the response of a post request. I know how to check response result by checking all properties.But I think I have to much duplicate code.I want to check with Object.
this is code for properties check:

```java
      mockMvc.perform(
                post("/api/v1/clients/test")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(client))
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data").isEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.statusCode").isNumber())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.statusCode").value(200))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value("success"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.success").value(true));
```

the response body look like this

```json
{"statusCode":200,"message":"success","data":null,"success":true}
```

I have a java object

```java
public class ResponseResult {
    private boolean isSuccess;
    private int statusCode;
    private String message;
    private Object data;
}
```

I want to create a object, then check the object equal the response body. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your frontend you need to create same object as backend with all equal spelled properties.

Then when you subscribe to that endpoint, for example in angular you can do like this:

```
this.myService.test().subscribe(res:ResponseResult){
//here the 'res' will be your response object you recieve from backend
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.But I want to this with Spring boot MVC,in other word,I want to write this in java.

Comment: Ok what's your front end? or all java?

Comment: I write backend all in java.I only have backend and no front end. I usually use vue for my front end.